# Can someone explain the answer for c and d?

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I have a discrete math question.

I have this question, I have the answer, I just don't understand it:

Question: Let s be a string of length 2 with characters from {0, 1, 2}, and define statements
a, b, c, and d as follows:
a - the first character of s is 0;
b - the first character of s is 1;
c - the second character of s is 1;
d - the second character of s is 2.

Answer: The four statements correspond to the following sets of characters.
a − {00, 01, 02}, b − {10, 11, 12}, c − {01, 11, 21}, d − {02, 12, 12}

can someone explain why is that so? To a certain point I understand a and b. But I have no clue as to why the answer for d is that. For d why is the first character 0, 1, 1? isnt d supposed to be 02, 12, 22??

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For (c), the second character must be $1$, and you've listed all of the possibilities. Notice how the first character can be any of $1$, $2$, or $3$ so there are $3$ such strings. In a very analogous way, for (d), the second character is $2$, and there are again $3$ strings.

Comment: @SammyBlack You mean first character may be 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. That's a typo.

Comment: @SammyBlack i got the second character but for d why is the first character 0, 1, 1? isnt d supposed to be 02, 12, 22??

Comment: It looks like an error in the answer you were given, I agree that $d$ should be 02,12,22.